# How to customize the code of autofill according to non-contiguous data on adjacent column

Tags: vba, customization, autofill

[Screenshot of one file is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU6MS.jpg) I have a non-contiguous data on F column which is NOT starting from the beginning and there are gaps on it (i.e. data on F column starts on cell 244, ends on 899, and starts on 2765 and ends on 4948, and so on). Formula on G is to find the minimum value of column F in last 29 cells before the selected cell, and formula on H is to calculate the average of column G in last 29 cells before the selected cell. I want to apply formulas on G and H columns by autofill, but:

- formulas in G column must start 29 rows below the start of data in F column,
- formulas in H column must start 44 rows below the start of data in F column,
- and formulas on both G and H column must stop when data on F stops
- The maximum number of rows with data is 15 000

I have 300 something such files and the data on F column has gaps without not any pattern.

In my previous task, I used the autofill data below, which makes autofill till the end of data on given column;

```
lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("E1:E" & lastRow) = "=C1+D1"
```

How can I customize this code according to my needs? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: As you progress down the sections, the formulas will be changing. So it would be best to share them. Also, you could share a working code (without gaps is ok) and maybe some screenshots and/or sample data. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66779838/edit) your question at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have just edited my question accordingly.